# How to vectorize the dot product between segments of a trajectory

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a function for the dot product between consecutive segments of a trajectory (xy coordinates). The result is as expected but the "for loop" makes it very slow.

```
In [94]:
def func1(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    out = np.zeros(size)
    for i in range(size):
        p1, p2 = xy[i], xy[i+s]     #segment 1
        p3, p4 = xy[i+s], xy[i+2*s] #segment 2
        out[i] = np.dot(p1-p2, p4-p3)
    return out

xy = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[2,4],[5,2],[9,9],[1,1]])
func1(xy, 2)

Out[94]:
array([-16.,  15.,  32.,  31., -14.])
```

I looked for a way to vectorize the above, hoping to make it much faster. Here is what I came up with:

```
In [95]:
def func2(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    p1 = xy[0:size]
    p2 = xy[s:size+s]
    p3 = p2
    p4 = xy[2*s:size+2*s]
    return np.diagonal(np.dot((p1-p2), (p4-p3).T))

func2(xy, 2)

Out[95]:
array([-16,  15,  32,  31, -14])
```

Unfortunately, the dot product produces a square matrix from which I have to take the diagonal:

```
In [96]:
print np.dot((p1-p2), (p4-p3).T)
np.diagonal(np.dot((p1-p2), (p4-p3).T))

[[-16  10  16 -24  10]
 [-24  15  24 -36  15]
 [-32  20  32 -48  20]
 [ 20 -13 -18  31 -14]
 [ 32 -18 -40  44 -14]]

Out[96]:
array([-16,  15,  32,  31, -14])
```

My solution is really awful. It improves speed by only a ratio of 2 and more importantly it is now not scalable. My average trajectories have several ten thousands points which means that I'll have to deal with huge matrices.

Do you guys know of a better way?
Thank you

EDIT:
Awesome! einsum is definitively the solution. In my frustration I wrote the dot product myself. I know, not very readable and it defeats the purpose of using optimized libraries but here it is anyway (func4). Speed is on par with einsum.

```
def func4(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    tmp1 = xy[0:size] - xy[s:size+s]
    tmp2 = xy[2*s:size+2*s] - xy[s:size+s]
    return tmp1[:, 0] * tmp2[:, 0] + tmp1[:, 1] * tmp2[:, 1]
```

Comment: for larger arrays your `func4` is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea in `func2` leads naturally to using `np.einsum`.

The good part of `func2` is that it only computes `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` once as
larger arrays instead of small pieces as in `func1`.

The bad part of `func2` is that it does a lot of dot products that you don't
care about.

That's where `einsum` comes in. It is a more flexible version of `np.dot`.
Whenever you are computing a sum of products, think about using `np.einsum`. It
is likely to be among the fastest (if not *the* fastest) way to compute the
quantity using NumPy.

```
def func3(xy, s):
    size = xy.shape[0]-2*s
    p1 = xy[0:size]
    p2 = xy[s:size+s]
    p3 = p2
    p4 = xy[2*s:size+2*s]
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->i', p1-p2, p4-p3)
```

The subscript string `'ij,ij->i'` has the following meaning:

There are two parts to the subscript string `'ij,ij->i'`: before the arrow
(`->`), on the left, `ij,ij` and after the arrow, `i`.

On the left, the `ij` before the comma refers to the subscripts for `p1-p2`, and
the `ij` after the comma refer to the subscripts for `p4-p3`.

*The Einstein summation notation sums over repeated subscripts that do not appear after the arrow*. In this case, `j` is repeated and does not appear after the arrow.

So for each `i`, the sum `(p1-p2)[i,j]*(p4-p3)[i,j]` is computed, where the sum runs over all `j`. The result is an array indexed by `i`.

---

Sanity check:

```
In [90]: np.allclose(func1(xy, 2), func3(xy, 2))
Out[90]: True
```

---

Here is a benchmark: on an array `xy` of shape (9000, 2), showing using `einsum`
is 450x faster that func1 and 7470x faster than `func2`:

```
In [13]: xy = np.tile(xy, (1000,1))

In [14]: %timeit func1(xy, 2)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit func2(xy, 2)
1 loops, best of 3: 686 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit func3(xy, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.8 µs per loop
```

The OP's `func4` performs even better than `func3`!

```
In [92]: %timeit func4(xy, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.1 µs per loop
```

I think the reason why `func4` is beating `einsum` here is because the cost of setting of the loop in `einsum` for just 2 iterations is too expensive compared to just manually writing out the sum.

Answer (score 3):

`einsum` is a good tool for generalizing the `dot` product.  Playing around with it, I can reproduce your numbers with:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',p1-p2,p4-p3)
```

'ij,kj' produces `dot(p1-p2, (p4-p3).T)`; the 'i...,i...->i' does the diagonal - all in one step.

---

as a spin off from your cross-product question I tried

```
tmp11,tmp21),tmp11[:,0]*tmp21[:,0]+tmp11[:,1]*tmp21[:,1])
```

For 5000 row arrays it is almost 2x the speed of the einsum calc.