# Is there a vectorized way to apply a transformation matrix to a group of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, transformation, coordinate-transformation

Imagine you have a group of vectors, e.g. in the form of a trajectory. Is there a vectorized way of applying the transformation matrix to all data points at once, or are you stuck with a for-loop? Here is some sample code:

```py
import numpy as np


angle = np.deg2rad(90)
rotM = np.array(
    [
        [np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle), 0],
        [np.sin(angle),  np.cos(angle), 0],
        [            0,              0, 1],
    ]
)

# trajectory with columns t, x, y, z
trajectory = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 1, 0],
        [3, 3, 2, 0],
        [4, 4, 3, 1],
        [5, 6, 4, 2],
        [6, 9, 5, 3],
    ]
)

# transform coordinates
for i in range(len(trajectory)):
    trajectory[i][1:] = np.dot(rotM, trajectory[i][1:])
```

All I found so far is [`numpy.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html), and these two posts ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47095513/5472354), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28130787/5472354)), none of which seem to apply to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, use broadcasting along with `np.matmul`/`@`. You can multiply a 3x3 martrix by an Nx3x1 array of vectors:

```
trajectory[:, 1:] = rotM @ trajectory[:, 1:, None]
```

A cleaner and more flexible solution might be to use `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation` objects instead of hand-crafting the matrix yourself:

```
rotM = Rotation.from_euler('z', angle)
trajectory[:, 1:] = rotM.apply(trajectory[:, 1:])
```

No need to add shim dimensions in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I didn't know about the `@` syntax at all. So is that just an abbreviation of `np.matmul`, or something completely different? Using `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation` makes a lot of sense, however the MWE was really just a simple example. For my actual data, all I have is the matrix; I neither know the rotation axis nor the angle (generally there will be multiple), though I guess there is a tool to figure this out as well.

Comment: @mapf. `np.matmul` is the function implementing `@` for numpy arrays